# Genetic Algorithm - creatures in 2d world are not learning

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

Goal -
I am trying to implement a genetic algorithm to optimise the fitness of a
species of creatures in a simulated two-dimensional world. The world contains edible foods, placed at random, and a population of monsters (your basic zombies).  I need the algorithm to find behaviours that keep the creatures well fed and not dead.

What i have done -

So i start off by generating a 11x9 2d array in numpy, this is filled with random floats between 0 and 1. I then use np.matmul to go through each row of the array and multiply all of the random weights by all of the percepts (w1+p1*w2+p2....w9+p9) = a1.

This first generation is run and I then evaluate the fitness of each creature using (energy + (time of death * 100)). From this I build a list of creatures who performed above the average fitness. I then take the best of these "elite" creatures and put them back into the next population. For the remaining space I use a crossover function which takes two randomly selected "elite" creatures and mixes their genes. I have tested two different crossover functions one which does a two point crossover on each row and one which takes a row from each parent until the new child has a complete chromosome. My issue is that the creatures just don't really seem to be learning, at 75 turns I will only get 1 survivor every so often.

I am fully aware this might not be enough to go off but I am truly stuck on this and cannot figure out how to get these creatures to learn even though I think I am implementing the correct procedures. Occasionally I will get a 3-4 survivors rather than 1 or 2 but it appears to occur completely randomly, doesn't seem like there is much learning happening.

Below is the main section of code, it includes everything I have done but none of the provided code for the simulation

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from cosc343world import Creature, World
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import itertools


# You can change this number to specify how many generations creatures are going to evolve over.
numGenerations = 2000

# You can change this number to specify how many turns there are in the simulation of the world for a given generation.
numTurns = 75

# You can change this number to change the world type.  You have two choices - world 1 or 2 (described in
# the assignment 2 pdf document).
worldType=2

# You can change this number to modify the world size.
gridSize=24

# You can set this mode to True to have the same initial conditions for each simulation in each generation - good
# for development, when you want to have some determinism in how the world runs from generation to generation.
repeatableMode=False

# This is a class implementing you creature a.k.a MyCreature.  It extends the basic Creature, which provides the
# basic functionality of the creature for the world simulation.  Your job is to implement the AgentFunction
# that controls creature's behaviour by producing actions in response to percepts.
class MyCreature(Creature):

    # Initialisation function.  This is where your creature
    # should be initialised with a chromosome in a random state.  You need to decide the format of your
    # chromosome and the model that it's going to parametrise.
    #
    # Input: numPercepts - the size of the percepts list that the creature will receive in each turn
    #        numActions - the size of the actions list that the creature must create on each turn
    def __init__(self, numPercepts, numActions):

        # Place your initialisation code here.  Ideally this should set up the creature's chromosome
        # and set it to some random state.
        #self.chromosome = np.random.uniform(0, 10, size=numActions)
        self.chromosome = np.random.rand(11,9)
        self.fitness = 0
        #print(self.chromosome[1][1].size)

        # Do not remove this line at the end - it calls the constructors of the parent class.
        Creature.__init__(self)


    # This is the implementation of the agent function, which will be invoked on every turn of the simulation,
    # giving your creature a chance to perform an action.  You need to implement a model here that takes its parameters
    # from the chromosome and produces a set of actions from the provided percepts.
    #
    # Input: percepts - a list of percepts
    #        numAction - the size of the actions list that needs to be returned
    def AgentFunction(self, percepts, numActions):

        # At the moment the percepts are ignored and the actions is a list of random numbers.  You need to
        # replace this with some model that maps percepts to actions.  The model
        # should be parametrised by the chromosome.

        #actions = np.random.uniform(0, 0, size=numActions)

        actions = np.matmul(self.chromosome, percepts)

        return actions.tolist()


# This function is called after every simulation, passing a list of the old population of creatures, whose fitness
# you need to evaluate and whose chromosomes you can use to create new creatures.
#
# Input: old_population - list of objects of MyCreature type that participated in the last simulation.  You
#                         can query the state of the creatures by using some built-in methods as well as any methods
#                         you decide to add to MyCreature class.  The length of the list is the size of
#                         the population.  You need to generate a new population of the same size.  Creatures from
#                         old population can be used in the new population - simulation will reset them to their
#                         starting state (not dead, new health, etc.).
#
# Returns: a list of MyCreature objects of the same length as the old_population.

def selection(old_population, fitnessScore):
    elite_creatures = []
    for individual in old_population:
        if individual.fitness > fitnessScore:
            elite_creatures.append(individual)

    elite_creatures.sort(key=lambda x: x.fitness, reverse=True)

    return elite_creatures

def crossOver(creature1, creature2):
    child1 = MyCreature(11, 9)
    child2 = MyCreature(11, 9)
    child1_chromosome = []
    child2_chromosome = []

    #print("parent1", creature1.chromosome)
    #print("parent2", creature2.chromosome)

    for row in range(11):
        chromosome1 = creature1.chromosome[row]
        chromosome2 = creature2.chromosome[row]

        index1 = random.randint(1, 9 - 2)
        index2 = random.randint(1, 9 - 2)

        if index2 >= index1:
            index2 += 1
        else:  # Swap the two cx points
            index1, index2 = index2, index1

        child1_chromosome.append(np.concatenate([chromosome1[:index1],chromosome2[index1:index2],chromosome1[index2:]]))
        child2_chromosome.append(np.concatenate([chromosome2[:index1],chromosome1[index1:index2],chromosome2[index2:]]))

    child1.chromosome = child1_chromosome
    child2.chromosome = child2_chromosome

    #print("child1", child1_chromosome)

    return(child1, child2)

def crossOverRows(creature1, creature2):
    child = MyCreature(11, 9)

    child_chromosome = np.empty([11,9])

    i = 0

    while i < 11:
        if i != 10:
            child_chromosome[i] = creature1.chromosome[i]
            child_chromosome[i+1] = creature2.chromosome[i+1]
        else:
            child_chromosome[i] = creature1.chromosome[i]

        i += 2

    child.chromosome = child_chromosome

    return child

    # print("parent1", creature1.chromosome[:3])
    # print("parent2", creature2.chromosome[:3])
    # print("crossover rows ", child_chromosome[:3])


def newPopulation(old_population):
    global numTurns

    nSurvivors = 0
    avgLifeTime = 0
    fitnessScore = 0
    fitnessScores = []

    # For each individual you can extract the following information left over
    # from the evaluation.  This will allow you to figure out how well an individual did in the
    # simulation of the world: whether the creature is dead or not, how much
    # energy did the creature have a the end of simulation (0 if dead), the tick number
    # indicating the time of creature's death (if dead).  You should use this information to build
    # a fitness function that scores how the individual did in the simulation.
    for individual in old_population:

        # You can read the creature's energy at the end of the simulation - it will be 0 if creature is dead.
        energy = individual.getEnergy()

        # This method tells you if the creature died during the simulation
        dead = individual.isDead()

        # If the creature is dead, you can get its time of death (in units of turns)
        if dead:
            timeOfDeath = individual.timeOfDeath()
            avgLifeTime += timeOfDeath
        else:
            nSurvivors += 1
            avgLifeTime += numTurns

        if individual.isDead() == False:
            timeOfDeath = numTurns

        individual.fitness = energy + (timeOfDeath * 100)
        fitnessScores.append(individual.fitness)
        fitnessScore += individual.fitness
        #print("fitnessscore", individual.fitness, "energy", energy, "time of death", timeOfDeath, "is dead", individual.isDead())

    fitnessScore = fitnessScore / len(old_population)

    eliteCreatures = selection(old_population, fitnessScore)

    print(len(eliteCreatures))

    newSet = []

    for i in range(int(len(eliteCreatures)/2)):
        if eliteCreatures[i].isDead() == False:
            newSet.append(eliteCreatures[i])

    print(len(newSet), " elites added to pop")

    remainingRequired = w.maxNumCreatures() - len(newSet)

    i = 1

    while i in range(int(remainingRequired)):
        newSet.append(crossOver(eliteCreatures[i], eliteCreatures[i-1])[0])
        if i >= (len(eliteCreatures)-2):
            i = 1
        i += 1

        remainingRequired = w.maxNumCreatures() - len(newSet)


    # Here are some statistics, which you may or may not find useful
    avgLifeTime = float(avgLifeTime)/float(len(population))
    print("Simulation stats:")
    print("  Survivors    : %d out of %d" % (nSurvivors, len(population)))
    print("  Average Fitness Score :", fitnessScore)
    print("  Avg life time: %.1f turns" % avgLifeTime)

    # The information gathered above should allow you to build a fitness function that evaluates fitness of
    # every creature.  You should show the average fitness, but also use the fitness for selecting parents and
    # spawning then new creatures.


    # Based on the fitness you should select individuals for reproduction and create a
    # new population.  At the moment this is not done, and the same population with the same number
    # of individuals is returned for the next generation.

    new_population = newSet

    return new_population

# Pygame window sometime doesn't spawn unless Matplotlib figure is not created, so best to keep the following two
# calls here.  You might also want to use matplotlib for plotting average fitness over generations.
plt.close('all')
fh=plt.figure()

# Create the world.  The worldType specifies the type of world to use (there are two types to chose from);
# gridSize specifies the size of the world, repeatable parameter allows you to run the simulation in exactly same way.
w = World(worldType=worldType, gridSize=gridSize, repeatable=repeatableMode)

#Get the number of creatures in the world
numCreatures = w.maxNumCreatures()

#Get the number of creature percepts
numCreaturePercepts = w.numCreaturePercepts()

#Get the number of creature actions
numCreatureActions = w.numCreatureActions()

# Create a list of initial creatures - instantiations of the MyCreature class that you implemented
population = list()
for i in range(numCreatures):
   c = MyCreature(numCreaturePercepts, numCreatureActions)
   population.append(c)

# Pass the first population to the world simulator
w.setNextGeneration(population)

# Runs the simulation to evaluate the first population
w.evaluate(numTurns)

# Show the visualisation of the initial creature behaviour (you can change the speed of the animation to 'slow',
# 'normal' or 'fast')
w.show_simulation(titleStr='Initial population', speed='normal')

for i in range(numGenerations):
    print("\nGeneration %d:" % (i+1))

    # Create a new population from the old one
    population = newPopulation(population)

    # Pass the new population to the world simulator
    w.setNextGeneration(population)

    # Run the simulation again to evaluate the next population
    w.evaluate(numTurns)

    # Show the visualisation of the final generation (you can change the speed of the animation to 'slow', 'normal' or
    # 'fast')
    if i==numGenerations-1:
        w.show_simulation(titleStr='Final population', speed='normal')
```

Comment: So one thing that I have experienced when doing genetic algorithms (very minimal), is that it really comes down to how your data is formatted. What do your "genes" represent? Is it a set of motions for example? Or is it more geared toward a policy? If your agents aren't learning, but are mutating correctly, then the problem is most likely in your fitness function or with what the genes are representing.